# I keep getting "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" error message when i am trying to write to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file

```
def writeToFile(self):
 file= open("C:\\Users\\Gabri\\Pictures\\newInternationalCases.csv", "w", newline='')
 with file:
  write = csv.writer(file);
 write.writerow(self.recordList);
```

This is the code above, my intention is for it to create the file and write to it. The "recordList" is a 2D list that I want to write into the file

Answer (score 1):

```
path = r"C:\Users\Gabri\Pictures\newInternationalCases.csv"
with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(self.recordList)
```

Answer (score -1):

`with file` closes the file at the end of the block, so you can only write inside the `with`.

```
with file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    # Inside 'with' block
    write.writerow(self.recordList)
```

Also note that it is fairly normal to put `open` at the top of `with`:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Gabri\Pictures\newInternationalCases.csv"
with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(self.recordList)
```

Comment: so if i indent it within the with block it should work?

Comment: Yes, you should indent it to be inside the `with` block.